# Restore All Deleted Files to the Current Working Directory from Git

Tags: reactjs, git, github, git-commit

I have accidentally deleted all files in frontend directory from my project. This is where I have everything. I can see all those files in the **changes** pane and it is marked with **D**. Is there any way I could retrieve completely everything.

Now, this is how my current project looks

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use "git reset --hard"